# Meaning of "Honor Brite" in an Alan Parsons Project song

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, lyrics, songs

In "Games People Play" from album "The turn of the friendly card" by the Alan Parsons Project, we hear:

> Games people play/You take take it or you leave it/Things that they
>   say/*Honor Brite*/If I promise you the Moon and the Stars/Would you
>   believe it/Games people play in the middle of the night

What does *Honor Brite* mean in this context? I have heard that the song might bear links with [Eric Berne's eponymous psychology book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Games_People_Play_(book)), does it help?

Comment: [*Methinks it were an easy leap to pluck **bright honour** from the pale-faced moon,*](http://www.finedictionary.com/Honour%20bright!.html) wrote William Shakespeare more than 400 years ago. The (primarily BrE) affirmation/oath-swearing *[On my] honour bright* is pretty dated today.

Comment: You may hear 'honor brite', but are those the actual lyrics?  Could they be 'are not right'?

Comment: @AmI I'll dig my old CDs to check again in the original sleeve

Comment: @Aml, Laurent, I checked my original *LP jacket*, and it is correct: *Honor Brite*...

Comment: In the 1952 movie "O. Henry's Full House"; Richard Widmark taunts Dale Robertson with , used in a pejorative sense, catcalls of being "Honour Bright".

Comment: I remember “honor bright” or (“brite”) from the jacket too, and it *sounds* like that, but all the online sources show “aren’t right” or “aren’t alright _[sic]_”.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That use reflects this colloquial sense:

> P9. *colloq.* ***honour bright***: used as an expression of, or interrogatively as an appeal to, one's honour or sincerity. Cf. *honest Injun* at Injun *n.* b. Now somewhat arch.
>
> *(["honour | honor, n.".](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/88227#eid156161672) OED Online. March 2014. Oxford University Press. Accessed March 08, 2016.)*

Its meaning is an interjected "on my honor it's true what I say!" In the context of the surrounding lyrics, it emphasizes that what is said during the games "in the middle of the night" is neither sincere nor true.

Answer (score 2):

The origin of this phrase comes from *Troilus and Cressida*, by William Shakespeare (1609):

*"Perseverance, dear my lord, 
Keeps **honor bright**: to have done, is to hang 
Quite out of fashion, like a rusty mail 
In monumental mockery."*

Comment: This does not answer the question. This tells of the origin, but not the meaning. Please edit your question to include the meaning or it will most likely be deleted.